# IPAddress.[Try]Parse parses 192.168 to 192.0.0.168

Tags: c#, networking, .net-4.0, ip-address

I have the following scenario:

```
IPAddress ip;
IPAddress.TryParse("192.168", out ip);    
if(ip == null){//do something with IP}
```

I would expect the parsing to fail, instead it is parsed as "192.0.0.168". What am I missing here? (IPAddress.Parse works the same)

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation of [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx):

> The number of parts (each part is separated by a period) in ipString determines how the IP address is constructed. A one part address is stored directly in the network address. A two part address, convenient for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the network address. A three part address, convenient for specifying a class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two bytes of the network address. For example:

```
Number of parts and example ipString | IPv4 address for IPAddress
1 -- "65536"                         | 0.0.255.255
2 -- "20.2"                          | 20.0.0.2
2 -- "20.65535"                      | 20.0.255.255
3 -- "128.1.2"                       | 128.1.0.2
```

Comment: this looks a lot like John Koerners answer.. :)

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx), which includes similar examples to yours, is pretty clear:

> The number of parts (each part is separated by a period) in ipString
>   determines how the IP address is constructed. A one part address is
>   stored directly in the network address. A two part address, convenient
>   for specifying a class A address, puts the leading part in the first
>   byte and the trailing part in the right-most three bytes of the
>   network address. A three part address, convenient for specifying a
>   class B address, puts the first part in the first byte, the second
>   part in the second byte, and the final part in the right-most two
>   bytes of the network address.

```
Number of parts and example ipString      IPv4 address for IPAddress    
====================================================================
1 -- "65536"                              0.0.255.255
2 -- "20.2"                               20.0.0.2
2 -- "20.65535"                           20.0.255.255
3 -- "128.1.2"                            128.1.0.2
```

Comment: this looks a  lot like Odeds answer.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Type `http://192.168` into your browser's address bar. What happens?

This is expected behaviour.